# href from json in android xml

Tags: android, android-xml

I have and app and on my main menu page I want to load a clickable ad (href) from json.

example  :

```
'nationalad': 
 "<"img src=\"http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com\/images\/national\/fullrz_2_4e657ae4df4ee_mywebsite.JPG\">"
```

This is the value I am getting back from json  :

```
"<"img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/national/fullrz_2_4e657ae4df4ee_kickintheapp.JPG">
```

How do I set this in my xml page?  Do I use a view or webview or an image /image button?

Completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a WebView, and show the data by using [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)`(null, yourData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Comment: This is working for the text I'm passing in but not for the picture.     WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                     webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, valArray.getString(1), "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Answer (score 0):

Hmm  this works great for the first run what when I re-run the app the webview is not showing.  The only thing that changes is that the image coming in is different on each load.

```
webView2.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, valArray.getString(1), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```